# docker-compose how to run container with bind 1-to-1 ports on ip aliasing interface

Tags: docker, ip, containers, docker-compose

i have many IP's on my interface:
`inet 10.100.131.115/24 brd 10.100.131.255 scope global br0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet 10.100.131.120/24 brd 10.100.131.255 scope global secondary br0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet 10.100.131.121/24 brd 10.100.131.255 scope global secondary br0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet 10.100.131.122/24 brd 10.100.131.255 scope global secondary br0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever`

docker-compose.yml:
`version: '2'
services:
    app:
        image: app
        network_mode: "bridge"
        volumes:
         - /root/docker/app/project/:/root/:ro
        ports:
         - "7999:7999"
        network_mode: "bridge"`

if i up single container all good:
`docker-compose ps
Name                  Command               State           Ports

docker_app_1   /bin/sh -c uwsgi --ini wsg ...   Up      0.0.0.0:7999->7999/tcp`

but when i trying scale my app i got error (_ofc, because 7999 is alredy used by docker_app_1_):
`docker-compose scale app=2`
WARNING: The "app" service specifies a port on the host.
If multiple containers for this service are created on a single host, the port will clash.
Creating and starting docker_app_2 ... error

ERROR: for docker_app_2  Cannot start service app:  b'driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint docker_app_2 (xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx...):

> Bind for 0.0.0.0:7999 failed: port is already allocated'

**Can i tell docker-compose to use all IP's from interface which using IP alising?**
*i need 1 IP from interface:7999 -> docker container:7999*

Answer (score 1):

You can map specific IP's to a container rather than the default of 0.0.0.0. This is not scaling a single service though.

```
services:
  whatever:
    ports:
      - '10.100.131.121:7999:7999/tcp'
  another:
    ports:
      - '10.100.131.122:7999:7999/tcp'
```